One Stage/Job in Spark application only running on one executor
I have been running some tests regarding the execution of Spark and I have noticed a weird behaviour present in one of my tests. My spark cluster consists of 1 master node and 4 workers node, and the test that where I observe this behaviour is one where I am loading two tables/CSV's (they are both around 11.5GB in size and they are both loaded into HDFS prior to running the Spark application) into Dataframes, joining them, and then writing the output back to HDFS. The code I am using is below:
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

input_path_1 = "hdfs://10.10.1.1:9000/table-1-11.5GB.csv"
input_path_2 = "hdfs://10.10.1.1:9000/table-2-11.5GB.csv"
output_path = "hdfs://10.10.1.1:9000/output.csv"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("PysparkTestJoin").getOrCreate()

    spark_df_1 = spark.read.option("header", True).csv(input_path_1)
    spark_df_2 = spark.read.option("header", True).csv(input_path_2)

    joined_df = spark_df_1.join(spark_df_2, spark_df_1.Table1Key == spark_df_2.Table2Key, "inner")

    joined_df.write.csv(output_path)

    spark.stop()

When I run this on my cluster, I see that Spark divides the execution into 5 stages, the first two of which are loading the two CSV files into Dataframes. However, the issue arises in the next two stages, where from what I can tell, are the map stages in preparation for the final shuffle read stage. Below is the relevant part in the Spark EventLog
{"Event":"SparkListenerTaskStart","Stage ID":2,"Stage Attempt ID":0,"Task Info":{"Task ID":158,"Index":156,"Attempt":0,"Partition ID":156,"Launch Time":1725290560028,"Executor ID":"2","Host":"10.10.1.1","Locality":"ANY","Speculative":false,"Getting Result Time":0,"Finish Time":0,"Failed":false,"Killed":false,"Accumulables":[]}}
{"Event":"SparkListenerTaskStart","Stage ID":2,"Stage Attempt ID":0,"Task Info":{"Task ID":159,"Index":157,"Attempt":0,"Partition ID":157,"Launch Time":1725290560029,"Executor ID":"0","Host":"10.10.1.2","Locality":"ANY","Speculative":false,"Getting Result Time":0,"Finish Time":0,"Failed":false,"Killed":false,"Accumulables":[]}}
{"Event":"SparkListenerTaskStart","Stage ID":2,"Stage Attempt ID":0,"Task Info":{"Task ID":160,"Index":158,"Attempt":0,"Partition ID":158,"Launch Time":1725290560029,"Executor ID":"1","Host":"10.10.1.4","Locality":"ANY","Speculative":false,"Getting Result Time":0,"Finish Time":0,"Failed":false,"Killed":false,"Accumulables":[]}}
{"Event":"SparkListenerTaskStart","Stage ID":2,"Stage Attempt ID":0,"Task Info":{"Task ID":161,"Index":159,"Attempt":0,"Partition ID":159,"Launch Time":1725290560030,"Executor ID":"3","Host":"10.10.1.3","Locality":"ANY","Speculative":false,"Getting Result Time":0,"Finish Time":0,"Failed":false,"Killed":false,"Accumulables":[]}}
{"Event":"SparkListenerTaskStart","Stage ID":3,"Stage Attempt ID":0,"Task Info":{"Task ID":162,"Index":0,"Attempt":0,"Partition ID":0,"Launch Time":1725290572421,"Executor ID":"1","Host":"10.10.1.4","Locality":"ANY","Speculative":false,"Getting Result Time":0,"Finish Time":0,"Failed":false,"Killed":false,"Accumulables":[]}}
{"Event":"SparkListenerTaskEnd","Stage ID":2,"Stage Attempt ID":0,"Task Type":"ShuffleMapTask","Task End Reason":{"Reason":"Success"},"Task Info":{"Task ID":44,"Index":42,"Attempt":0,"Partition ID":42,"Launch Time":1725290559976,"Executor ID":"1","Host":"10.10.1.4","Locality":"ANY","Speculative":false,"Getting Result Time":0,"Finish Time":1725290572425,"Failed":false,"Killed":false,"Accumulables":[{"ID":165,"Name":"number of output rows","Update":"125047","Value":"125047","Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true,"Metadata":"sql"},{"ID":204,"Name":"data size","Update":"158639872","Value":"158639872","Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true,"Metadata":"sql"},{"ID":223,"Name":"shuffle bytes written","Update":"78339783","Value":"78339783","Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true,"Metadata":"sql"},{"ID":224,"Name":"shuffle records written","Update":"125047","Value":"125047","Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true,"Metadata":"sql"},{"ID":225,"Name":"shuffle write time","Update":"483504037","Value":"483504037","Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true,"Metadata":"sql"},{"ID":226,"Name":"duration","Update":"9429","Value":"9429","Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true,"Metadata":"sql"},{"ID":227,"Name":"number of output rows","Update":"125047","Value":"125047","Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true,"Metadata":"sql"},{"ID":255,"Name":"internal.metrics.executorDeserializeTime","Update":1771,"Value":1771,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":256,"Name":"internal.metrics.executorDeserializeCpuTime","Update":299696183,"Value":299696183,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":257,"Name":"internal.metrics.executorRunTime","Update":10508,"Value":10508,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":258,"Name":"internal.metrics.executorCpuTime","Update":7037670369,"Value":7037670369,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":259,"Name":"internal.metrics.resultSize","Update":2123,"Value":2123,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":260,"Name":"internal.metrics.jvmGCTime","Update":789,"Value":789,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":261,"Name":"internal.metrics.resultSerializationTime","Update":5,"Value":5,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":283,"Name":"internal.metrics.shuffle.write.bytesWritten","Update":78339783,"Value":78339783,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":284,"Name":"internal.metrics.shuffle.write.recordsWritten","Update":125047,"Value":125047,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":285,"Name":"internal.metrics.shuffle.write.writeTime","Update":483504037,"Value":483504037,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":286,"Name":"internal.metrics.input.bytesRead","Update":72018020,"Value":72018020,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":287,"Name":"internal.metrics.input.recordsRead","Update":125047,"Value":125047,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true}]},"Task Executor Metrics":{"JVMHeapMemory":0,"JVMOffHeapMemory":0,"OnHeapExecutionMemory":0,"OffHeapExecutionMemory":0,"OnHeapStorageMemory":0,"OffHeapStorageMemory":0,"OnHeapUnifiedMemory":0,"OffHeapUnifiedMemory":0,"DirectPoolMemory":0,"MappedPoolMemory":0,"ProcessTreeJVMVMemory":0,"ProcessTreeJVMRSSMemory":0,"ProcessTreePythonVMemory":0,"ProcessTreePythonRSSMemory":0,"ProcessTreeOtherVMemory":0,"ProcessTreeOtherRSSMemory":0,"MinorGCCount":0,"MinorGCTime":0,"MajorGCCount":0,"MajorGCTime":0,"TotalGCTime":0},"Task Metrics":{"Executor Deserialize Time":1771,"Executor Deserialize CPU Time":299696183,"Executor Run Time":10508,"Executor CPU Time":7037670369,"Peak Execution Memory":0,"Result Size":2123,"JVM GC Time":789,"Result Serialization Time":5,"Memory Bytes Spilled":0,"Disk Bytes Spilled":0,"Shuffle Read Metrics":{"Remote Blocks Fetched":0,"Local Blocks Fetched":0,"Fetch Wait Time":0,"Remote Bytes Read":0,"Remote Bytes Read To Disk":0,"Local Bytes Read":0,"Total Records Read":0,"Remote Requests Duration":0,"Push Based Shuffle":{"Corrupt Merged Block Chunks":0,"Merged Fetch Fallback Count":0,"Merged Remote Blocks Fetched":0,"Merged Local Blocks Fetched":0,"Merged Remote Chunks Fetched":0,"Merged Local Chunks Fetched":0,"Merged Remote Bytes Read":0,"Merged Local Bytes Read":0,"Merged Remote Requests Duration":0}},"Shuffle Write Metrics":{"Shuffle Bytes Written":78339783,"Shuffle Write Time":483504037,"Shuffle Records Written":125047},"Input Metrics":{"Bytes Read":72018020,"Records Read":125047},"Output Metrics":{"Bytes Written":0,"Records Written":0},"Updated Blocks":[]}}
{"Event":"SparkListenerTaskStart","Stage ID":3,"Stage Attempt ID":0,"Task Info":{"Task ID":163,"Index":1,"Attempt":0,"Partition ID":1,"Launch Time":1725290572527,"Executor ID":"1","Host":"10.10.1.4","Locality":"ANY","Speculative":false,"Getting Result Time":0,"Finish Time":0,"Failed":false,"Killed":false,"Accumulables":[]}}
{"Event":"SparkListenerTaskEnd","Stage ID":2,"Stage Attempt ID":0,"Task Type":"ShuffleMapTask","Task End Reason":{"Reason":"Success"},"Task Info":{"Task ID":124,"Index":122,"Attempt":0,"Partition ID":122,"Launch Time":1725290560015,"Executor ID":"1","Host":"10.10.1.4","Locality":"ANY","Speculative":false,"Getting Result Time":0,"Finish Time":1725290572528,"Failed":false,"Killed":false,"Accumulables":[{"ID":165,"Name":"number of output rows","Update":"125046","Value":"250093","Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true,"Metadata":"sql"},{"ID":204,"Name":"data size","Update":"158642088","Value":"317281960","Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true,"Metadata":"sql"},{"ID":223,"Name":"shuffle bytes written","Update":"78318348","Value":"156658131","Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true,"Metadata":"sql"},{"ID":224,"Name":"shuffle records written","Update":"125046","Value":"250093","Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true,"Metadata":"sql"},{"ID":225,"Name":"shuffle write time","Update":"383134992","Value":"866639029","Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true,"Metadata":"sql"},{"ID":226,"Name":"duration","Update":"9649","Value":"19078","Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true,"Metadata":"sql"},{"ID":227,"Name":"number of output rows","Update":"125046","Value":"250093","Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true,"Metadata":"sql"},{"ID":255,"Name":"internal.metrics.executorDeserializeTime","Update":1701,"Value":3472,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":256,"Name":"internal.metrics.executorDeserializeCpuTime","Update":288881286,"Value":588577469,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":257,"Name":"internal.metrics.executorRunTime","Update":10639,"Value":21147,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":258,"Name":"internal.metrics.executorCpuTime","Update":6964641545,"Value":14002311914,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":259,"Name":"internal.metrics.resultSize","Update":2080,"Value":4203,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":260,"Name":"internal.metrics.jvmGCTime","Update":789,"Value":1578,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":283,"Name":"internal.metrics.shuffle.write.bytesWritten","Update":78318348,"Value":156658131,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":284,"Name":"internal.metrics.shuffle.write.recordsWritten","Update":125046,"Value":250093,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":285,"Name":"internal.metrics.shuffle.write.writeTime","Update":383134992,"Value":866639029,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":286,"Name":"internal.metrics.input.bytesRead","Update":72023940,"Value":144041960,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":287,"Name":"internal.metrics.input.recordsRead","Update":125046,"Value":250093,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true}]},"Task Executor Metrics":{"JVMHeapMemory":0,"JVMOffHeapMemory":0,"OnHeapExecutionMemory":0,"OffHeapExecutionMemory":0,"OnHeapStorageMemory":0,"OffHeapStorageMemory":0,"OnHeapUnifiedMemory":0,"OffHeapUnifiedMemory":0,"DirectPoolMemory":0,"MappedPoolMemory":0,"ProcessTreeJVMVMemory":0,"ProcessTreeJVMRSSMemory":0,"ProcessTreePythonVMemory":0,"ProcessTreePythonRSSMemory":0,"ProcessTreeOtherVMemory":0,"ProcessTreeOtherRSSMemory":0,"MinorGCCount":0,"MinorGCTime":0,"MajorGCCount":0,"MajorGCTime":0,"TotalGCTime":0},"Task Metrics":{"Executor Deserialize Time":1701,"Executor Deserialize CPU Time":288881286,"Executor Run Time":10639,"Executor CPU Time":6964641545,"Peak Execution Memory":0,"Result Size":2080,"JVM GC Time":789,"Result Serialization Time":0,"Memory Bytes Spilled":0,"Disk Bytes Spilled":0,"Shuffle Read Metrics":{"Remote Blocks Fetched":0,"Local Blocks Fetched":0,"Fetch Wait Time":0,"Remote Bytes Read":0,"Remote Bytes Read To Disk":0,"Local Bytes Read":0,"Total Records Read":0,"Remote Requests Duration":0,"Push Based Shuffle":{"Corrupt Merged Block Chunks":0,"Merged Fetch Fallback Count":0,"Merged Remote Blocks Fetched":0,"Merged Local Blocks Fetched":0,"Merged Remote Chunks Fetched":0,"Merged Local Chunks Fetched":0,"Merged Remote Bytes Read":0,"Merged Local Bytes Read":0,"Merged Remote Requests Duration":0}},"Shuffle Write Metrics":{"Shuffle Bytes Written":78318348,"Shuffle Write Time":383134992,"Shuffle Records Written":125046},"Input Metrics":{"Bytes Read":72023940,"Records Read":125046},"Output Metrics":{"Bytes Written":0,"Records Written":0},"Updated Blocks":[]}}
{"Event":"SparkListenerTaskStart","Stage ID":3,"Stage Attempt ID":0,"Task Info":{"Task ID":164,"Index":2,"Attempt":0,"Partition ID":2,"Launch Time":1725290572529,"Executor ID":"1","Host":"10.10.1.4","Locality":"ANY","Speculative":false,"Getting Result Time":0,"Finish Time":0,"Failed":false,"Killed":false,"Accumulables":[]}}
{"Event":"SparkListenerTaskEnd","Stage ID":2,"Stage Attempt ID":0,"Task Type":"ShuffleMapTask","Task End Reason":{"Reason":"Success"},"Task Info":{"Task ID":68,"Index":66,"Attempt":0,"Partition ID":66,"Launch Time":1725290559989,"Executor ID":"1","Host":"10.10.1.4","Locality":"ANY","Speculative":false,"Getting Result Time":0,"Finish Time":1725290572531,"Failed":false,"Killed":false,"Accumulables":[{"ID":165,"Name":"number of output rows","Update":"125041","Value":"375134","Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true,"Metadata":"sql"},{"ID":204,"Name":"data size","Update":"158638968","Value":"475920928","Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true,"Metadata":"sql"},{"ID":223,"Name":"shuffle bytes written","Update":"78299018","Value":"234957149","Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true,"Metadata":"sql"},{"ID":224,"Name":"shuffle records written","Update":"125041","Value":"375134","Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true,"Metadata":"sql"},{"ID":225,"Name":"shuffle write time","Update":"396082893","Value":"1262721922","Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true,"Metadata":"sql"},{"ID":226,"Name":"duration","Update":"9647","Value":"28725","Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true,"Metadata":"sql"},{"ID":227,"Name":"number of output rows","Update":"125041","Value":"375134","Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true,"Metadata":"sql"},{"ID":255,"Name":"internal.metrics.executorDeserializeTime","Update":1755,"Value":5227,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":256,"Name":"internal.metrics.executorDeserializeCpuTime","Update":299130312,"Value":887707781,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":257,"Name":"internal.metrics.executorRunTime","Update":10639,"Value":31786,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":258,"Name":"internal.metrics.executorCpuTime","Update":7091814241,"Value":21094126155,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":259,"Name":"internal.metrics.resultSize","Update":2080,"Value":6283,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":260,"Name":"internal.metrics.jvmGCTime","Update":789,"Value":2367,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":283,"Name":"internal.metrics.shuffle.write.bytesWritten","Update":78299018,"Value":234957149,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":284,"Name":"internal.metrics.shuffle.write.recordsWritten","Update":125041,"Value":375134,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":285,"Name":"internal.metrics.shuffle.write.writeTime","Update":396082893,"Value":1262721922,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":286,"Name":"internal.metrics.input.bytesRead","Update":72023636,"Value":216065596,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":287,"Name":"internal.metrics.input.recordsRead","Update":125041,"Value":375134,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true}]},"Task Executor Metrics":{"JVMHeapMemory":0,"JVMOffHeapMemory":0,"OnHeapExecutionMemory":0,"OffHeapExecutionMemory":0,"OnHeapStorageMemory":0,"OffHeapStorageMemory":0,"OnHeapUnifiedMemory":0,"OffHeapUnifiedMemory":0,"DirectPoolMemory":0,"MappedPoolMemory":0,"ProcessTreeJVMVMemory":0,"ProcessTreeJVMRSSMemory":0,"ProcessTreePythonVMemory":0,"ProcessTreePythonRSSMemory":0,"ProcessTreeOtherVMemory":0,"ProcessTreeOtherRSSMemory":0,"MinorGCCount":0,"MinorGCTime":0,"MajorGCCount":0,"MajorGCTime":0,"TotalGCTime":0},"Task Metrics":{"Executor Deserialize Time":1755,"Executor Deserialize CPU Time":299130312,"Executor Run Time":10639,"Executor CPU Time":7091814241,"Peak Execution Memory":0,"Result Size":2080,"JVM GC Time":789,"Result Serialization Time":0,"Memory Bytes Spilled":0,"Disk Bytes Spilled":0,"Shuffle Read Metrics":{"Remote Blocks Fetched":0,"Local Blocks Fetched":0,"Fetch Wait Time":0,"Remote Bytes Read":0,"Remote Bytes Read To Disk":0,"Local Bytes Read":0,"Total Records Read":0,"Remote Requests Duration":0,"Push Based Shuffle":{"Corrupt Merged Block Chunks":0,"Merged Fetch Fallback Count":0,"Merged Remote Blocks Fetched":0,"Merged Local Blocks Fetched":0,"Merged Remote Chunks Fetched":0,"Merged Local Chunks Fetched":0,"Merged Remote Bytes Read":0,"Merged Local Bytes Read":0,"Merged Remote Requests Duration":0}},"Shuffle Write Metrics":{"Shuffle Bytes Written":78299018,"Shuffle Write Time":396082893,"Shuffle Records Written":125041},"Input Metrics":{"Bytes Read":72023636,"Records Read":125041},"Output Metrics":{"Bytes Written":0,"Records Written":0},"Updated Blocks":[]}}
{"Event":"SparkListenerTaskStart","Stage ID":3,"Stage Attempt ID":0,"Task Info":{"Task ID":165,"Index":3,"Attempt":0,"Partition ID":3,"Launch Time":1725290572838,"Executor ID":"1","Host":"10.10.1.4","Locality":"ANY","Speculative":false,"Getting Result Time":0,"Finish Time":0,"Failed":false,"Killed":false,"Accumulables":[]}}

As you can see, from the EventLog, Spark starts all the tasks in Stage 2 distributed across the 4 nodes in the cluster; however, when it starts the tasks in Stage 3, it only assigns them to one executor (the one with IP 10.10.1.4). As well, after examining the JobLog, I find that Stage 3 finishes much earlier than Stage 2, which I find also to be strange as it seems that all the jobs in Stage 2 are just blocking, despite some of them not running on the executor with IP 10.10.1.4 (I don't believe there is a dependency between Stages 2 and 3 because they are both submitted at basically the same time so this seems very strange). The relevant part of the JobLog is shown below:

{
  "jobId" : 3,
  "name" : "csv at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0",
  "submissionTime" : "2024-09-02T15:22:39.943GMT",
  "completionTime" : "2024-09-02T15:23:21.801GMT",
  "stageIds" : [ 3 ],
  "jobTags" : [ ],
  "status" : "SUCCEEDED",
  "numTasks" : 160,
  "numActiveTasks" : 0,
  "numCompletedTasks" : 160,
  "numSkippedTasks" : 0,
  "numFailedTasks" : 0,
  "numKilledTasks" : 0,
  "numCompletedIndices" : 160,
  "numActiveStages" : 0,
  "numCompletedStages" : 1,
  "numSkippedStages" : 0,
  "numFailedStages" : 0,
  "killedTasksSummary" : { }
}, {
  "jobId" : 2,
  "name" : "csv at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0",
  "submissionTime" : "2024-09-02T15:22:39.837GMT",
  "completionTime" : "2024-09-02T15:24:21.020GMT",
  "stageIds" : [ 2 ],
  "jobTags" : [ ],
  "status" : "SUCCEEDED",
  "numTasks" : 160,
  "numActiveTasks" : 0,
  "numCompletedTasks" : 160,
  "numSkippedTasks" : 0,
  "numFailedTasks" : 0,
  "numKilledTasks" : 0,
  "numCompletedIndices" : 160,
  "numActiveStages" : 0,
  "numCompletedStages" : 1,
  "numSkippedStages" : 0,
  "numFailedStages" : 0,
  "killedTasksSummary" : { }
}

Lastly, another strange behaviour that I see is that at the end of the application, when I look at the aggregated metrics, I see that executor 10.10.1.4 actually has the shortest total time spent in tasks, despite the input size to all executors being relatively the same. The aggregated metrics are shown below:
https://i.sstatic.net/CLIhM5rk.png
In terms of configurations, my spark.defaults.conf file is below:
# spark.master                     spark://master:7077
spark.eventLog.enabled           true
spark.eventLog.dir               hdfs://10.10.1.1:9000/logging
spark.history.fs.logDirectory    hdfs://10.10.1.1:9000/logging
# spark.serializer                 org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
spark.driver.memory              30g
spark.executor.memory            30g
# spark.executor.extraJavaOptions  -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Dkey=value -Dnumbers="one two three"

and I am submitting the job using spark-submit as follows:
./spark-submit --master spark://10.10.1.1:7077 /users/<username>/join-test.py

I have looked online for other posts that had similar issues but I was unable to get a clear. I am very curious as to why the execution for my application is like this so if anybody could provide some insight or potential reasons, that would be greatly appreciated. If there is also any other information that others may find useful, please feel free to ask and I will be sure to provide it.
